# Multidimensional vector of class type

Tags: c++, vector

i would need a little help with vector of vector when type is class. "loadTruck" is my class. I want to store values from my class "loadTruck" into 2D vector in this order: vector(truck ,print). Both "truck" and "print" are type of class "loadTruck". I want acces to this vector: for example lets say that "print" is package and "truck" is truck. I want to get information about package in truck 1, with package id 20. I am absolutely confused with this.

```
vector<vector <loadTruck>> jedinecTruck;
loadTruck truck;

while (warehouseIsEmpty == False)
{
    truck.resetTruck();
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPackages; i++)
    {
        vector<loadTruck> print;
        if (store2D[i].checkIfPackageIsThere() == true)
        {
            truck.setPackageSize(store2D[i].getPackageWidth(), store2D[i].getPackageHeight());
            if (truck.checkIfPackageCanBeLoaded() == true)
            {
                print.push_back(truck);
                truck.loadPackageInTruck();
                store2D[i].deletePackage();
            }
        }
    }
    jedinecTruck.push_back(truck);

}
```

Version with 3D array,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
now programm is running well, but array is not good idea but i hope that it will help you to understand what i want to do. I need to use vector because i am not able to define first 2 elements of array, it depends on algorythm and is always changing. For this example i suppose that first two elements will be defined statically. 3 rd element got always 4 components.

```
    vector<loadTruck> jedinecTruck;
loadTruck truck;

int array[1][3][4];

while (wharehouseIsEmpty == false)
{

    truck.resetTruck();
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPackages; i++)
    {
        if (store2D[i].checkIfPackageIsThere() == true)
        {
            truck.setPackageSize(store2D[i].getPackageWidth(), store2D[i].getPackageHeight());
            if (truck.checkIfPackageCanBeLoaded() == true)
            {
                truck.loadPackageInTruck();
                store2D[i].deletePackage();
                array[0][i][0] = truck.getActualX1();
                array[0][i][1] = truck.getActualX2();
                array[0][i][2] = truck.getActualY1();
                array[0][i][3] = truck.getActualY2();
            }
        }
    }
    jedinecTruck.push_back(truck);
  }
```

Regards

Comment: And the question is....?

Comment: What _specific_ problem are you having?

Comment: I'm not following either your explanation of what you are trying to do or the logic of the code you have written. But I can see that `jedinecTruck.push_back(truck);` is an error. Is that what you question is about? If so then explain a little more about that.

Comment: yea problem is somewhere in vectors. code is not executable for some reason. I must have been doing something wrong with vectors. Just look functions which works with vectors

vector<vector <loadTruck>> jedinecTruck;
loadTruck truck;

truck.resetTruck();
vector<loadTruck> print;
 
truck.setPackageSize(store2D[i].getPackageWidth(), store2D[i].getPackageHeight());
if (truck.checkIfPackageCanBeLoaded() == true)
  
print.push_back(truck);
truck.loadPackageInTruck();

jedinecTruck.push_back(truck);

Comment: VStudio shows me problem at this line: jedinecTruck.push_back(truck);

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is closer to what you're trying to do:

```
vector<vector <loadTruck>> jedinecTruck;
loadTruck truck;

while (warehouseIsEmpty == False)
{
    truck.resetTruck();
    vector<loadTruck> print;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPackages; i++)
    {
        if (store2D[i].checkIfPackageIsThere() == true)
        {
            truck.setPackageSize(store2D[i].getPackageWidth(), store2D[i].getPackageHeight());
            if (truck.checkIfPackageCanBeLoaded() == true)
            {
                print.push_back(truck);
                truck.loadPackageInTruck();
                store2D[i].deletePackage();
            }
        }
    }
    jedinecTruck.push_back(print);

}
```

It's difficult to tell from your question, though.

Comment: Don't work . OK i will try to specify what i need. I need to use vectors like array in this way. If you got 2D array than you can make something like array2D[0][0] = value. But in this case array2D is type of class. So class array2D[0][0]. Instead of array i have to use vector.

Comment: Actually `array2D` is a vector, not a class.  A vector can be indexed the same way as an array, so `array2D[0][0]` does the same thing for a vector as it does for an array.  The problem I think in your code is you are using `push_back` to build the array dynamically in both dimensions, which isn't something you can do with an array.

Perhaps if you sized the vectors beforehand, and just use the index operators, as if it was an array instead of a vector, it would make more sense in figuring out where the problem really is.

Comment: Hi, pls check my question again, i add solution with array, thx